# How do i select the highest Valued Enum Entry with Part of the Name

Tags: c#, enums

Im looking for some C# code that will help me resolve the most appropriate template to use from and enum of all available templates

I have the following Enumeration

```
public enum TextTemplateTypeEnum
{
    BookingConfirmationV1 = 1,
    BookingConfirmationV2,
    BookingConfirmationTescoV1,
    BookingConfirmationV3,
    BookingConfirmationTescoV2,
    BookingConfirmationAsdaV1
}
```

then i need to resolve what template to use by selecting the correct and most recent Text template, so i will have the following variables passsed into the function

```
string customerName = Tesco;
ReasonEnum reason = ReasonEnum.BookingConfirmation
```

with that infomation i need to select the highest V* of the most appropriate template so for the above variables it would be

```
TextTemplateTypeEnum.BookingConfirmationTescoV2
```

but for instance in the customer name was

```
string customerName = Waitrose;
```

the correct template to return would be

```
TextTemplateTypeEnum.BookingConfirmationV3
```

Comment: This looks like you need to use `switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use `Enum.GetNames` to find the client name in the enum,order it by the last character, and then parse it to the enum again:

```
string client="Tesco";
var template=Enum.GetNames(typeof(TextTemplateTypeEnum))
                    .Where(x => x.Contains(client))
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Substring(o.Length - 1, 1))
                    .FirstOrDefault();

if (template==null)
{
        template = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TextTemplateTypeEnum))
                        .Where(x => x.Length == 21)
                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Substring(o.Length - 1, 1))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
}

TextTemplateTypeEnum t = (TextTemplateTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TextTemplateTypeEnum), template);
```

But this implementation has two possible problems. First is what happens when you reach version 10 for example,as it would end in `V10` and wouldn't be ordered as it should. The other is the "generic" template. In this code i look them by the size(21) but this is not very reliable. So, for this code to work, i suggest you change the generic template names to `BookingConfirmationGenericV2` (so you can look for "Generic" to get the right one) and the versions to at least 2 digits (`BookingConfirmationV01`).

**Edit**

Ok, now i realized that you had another enum for the reasons. Let's see if this method works for you:

```
static TextTemplateTypeEnum GetTemplate(string client,ReasonEnum reason)
{
    string reasonString = Enum.GetName(typeof(ReasonEnum), reason);
    string enumToSearch = reasonString + client;
    var template = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TextTemplateTypeEnum))
                .Where(x => x.Contains(enumToSearch))
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Substring(o.Length - 1, 1))
                .FirstOrDefault();

    if (template == null)
    {
        template = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TextTemplateTypeEnum))
                        .Where(x => x.StartsWith(reasonString) && x[reasonString.Length]=='V')
                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Substring(o.Length - 2, 2))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return (TextTemplateTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TextTemplateTypeEnum), template);
}
```

Usage:

```
string client = "Tesco";
ReasonEnum reason = ReasonEnum.NewStore;
TextTemplateTypeEnum t = GetTemplate(client, reason);
```

This would fail for versions from 10 on, that's why I suggested to use at least 2 digits for version.

Comment: need to find the Client and the reason as there will eventually be other enumns in there like 

NewStoreV1 & NewStoreTescoV1 so the reason and customer name need to be taken into account and the length cant be fixed. though the point about the versions is an important one thanks

Comment: I don't understand. I've tried this code using your `TextTemplateTypeEnum` and it works just right, both using 'Tesco' as client (returns BookingConfirmationTescoV2) and using 'Waitrose' (returns BookingConfirmationV3). Maybe there is any difference between the code you showed here and your real code...